# How to pass training data to a neural network

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following Python script:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

names = []
X = []
labels = []

with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        tokens = line.split(' ')
        names.append(tokens[0])
        labels.append(int(tokens[1]))

for img in range(len(names)):
    for name in names:
        img = np.array(Image.open(name))
        X.append(img)

X = np.array(X)

X_to_text_file = np.savetxt('x.txt', X.reshape(np.shape(X)), fmt='%5f')
X_data = import_data('x.txt')
```

Is this a correct way to pass image file names and their labels? Provided that `data.txt` has the following format:

```
img1.png 1
img2.png 1
img3.png 2
img4.png 1
img5.png 1
```

I'm also getting the error below on the line:     `X_to_text_file = np.savetxt('x.txt', X.reshape(np.shape(X)), fmt='%5f')`

```
TypeError: float argument required, not numpy.ndarray
```

Any ideas on that?

Thanks.

Comment: By default PIL images are imported as `0-255` integers. You probably want them loaded as float. Even better is to use `cv2` module to import images as it's faster and already in `numpy` format, or use `scipy` which is loaded as np as well.

Comment: what are you trying to do? do you want to create `x.txt` or to read it? Why are you reading `N**2` files iinstead of `N`?? What is `import_data`? What are `labels`?

Comment: @MaxU I would like to create "x.txt" and save the array there. "import_data" is a custom function that reads the data from the txt file. For N**2 file, maybe you mean that I have two loops? I'm trying to read the different image names. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: How this text file should look like? Why don't you want to use pickle format?

Comment: @MaxU I'm not really aware of the pickle format too much, so chose to do it that way

Comment: what kind of array do you want to save in the text file? Array of what (filenames or 3D numpy arrays representing images)? And what is `label` and how do you calculate it?

Comment: @MaxU I would like to save the 3D numpy arrays. As for the label, I preassign that in a text file as shown in my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Demo:

```
from glob import glob
import cv2

In [284]: names = glob(r'D:\temp\photo\*.jpg')

In [285]: names
Out[285]:
['D:\\temp\\photo\\20081116-IMG_0900.jpg',
 'D:\\temp\\photo\\20081116-IMG_0902.jpg']

In [286]: X = np.array([cv2.imread(f) for f in names])

In [287]: X.shape
Out[287]: (2, 2112, 2816, 3)
```